# $f(\overline{A}) \subset \overline{f(A)}$ for $f$ continuous

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Suppose $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map between two topological spaces.

Let $y \in f(\overline{A})$. Since $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$ then $\overline{A} = \bigcap A_i \supset A$, where each $A_i$ is closed. This implies
$$y \in f\big(\bigcap A_i\big) \implies y \in f(A_i) \quad \forall i.$$

This of course implies
$$ y \in \bigcap f(A_i).$$

However it seems this is a stronger result than what I would like to prove. Furthermore, it is not certain that each $f(A_i)$ is closed, and so we cannot say that $\bigcap f(A_i) = \overline{\bigcap f(A_i)}$. This leads me to believe I am either missing something or have made an error somewhere. Could I simply use the fact that each set is a subset of its closure to say
$$ y \in \bigcap f(A_i) \subset \overline{\bigcap f(A_i)}$$
or would I need something extra?

I am aware that this question has been asked before, but I was curious as to what is wrong about my approach. Thanks!

Comment: I’m not sure using intersections is helpful. Just use the definition of closure as the smallest closed container

Comment: @FShrike Wouldn't that be the same as taking the intersection of all closed sets containing $A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\overline{f(A)}$ is such that $f(A) \subset \overline{f(A)}$, then $f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})$ is closed ($f$ is continuous) and $A$ is contained in it. Since $f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})$ is closed, then $\overline{A} \subset f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})$, then $f(\overline{A}) \subset f (f^{-1}(\overline{f(A)})) \subset \overline{f(A)} $.